# Can a werewolf regenerate lost limbs?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, werewolf-the-forsaken

Pretty much see topic.  My Storyteller was wondering and I figured I'd look around.  I didn't see anything in the book about it specifically though I would figure losing a limb is Aggravated damage so they would heal it as a human would (and as such cannot regrow the limb).  Is this interpretation correct or am I missing something somewhere?

Answer (score 8):

### In First Edition, they can't. In Second Edition, they can.

The loss of a body part, like a limb or an eye, is a potential consequence of taking aggravated damage, whether from severe wounds or silvered weapons.

- In First Edition, werewolves don't regenerate aggravated damage, so they're stuck.
- Uratha in 2e heal aggravated damage at one point every four days (p.95). As is detailed on page WtF 94, "Werewolves who suffer from Tilts inflicted by aggravated damage, like missing arms or missing eyes, heal those Tilts when they heal the associated wound." It's an explicit change in the new book.

Comment: Even though you mentioned it already with mentioning the aggrevated damage I think it should be noted explicitely that in 2nd edition this ALSO encompasses limbs lost due to being cut off by silver weapons (thus even these lost limbs are regenerated now).

Comment: @ThomasE. Added to the body of the post.

Answer (score 2):

To counter Jadasc's answer, the answer is yes in both versions of the game. Regenerating lost limbs/organs/fingers/eyes/etc is covered in Blood of the Wolf (p.18), costing a Willpower Dot and requiring an extended healing action (required successes based on the limb/organ lost).

Also, while werewolves don't regenerate aggravated damage (i.e. get a faster rate of healing), they do still heal aggravated damage at normal human rates.